# f satisfies functional equation f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) and is Riemann integrable, show f(x)=cx

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is Riemann integral over every interval of finite length and $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for every pair of real numbers $x$ and $y$, show that $f(x)=cx$ where $c=f(1)$.

I am able to prove if the function were to be continuous. But how to use integrability property to prove the same, especially for irrational numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's Riemann integrable on compact intervals, hence continuous at some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then consider $f(y + x_0) - f(x_0)= f(y)$. Taking $y \to 0$ shows continuity at $0$ (since $f(0) = 0$).

For *arbitrary* $s$, we have

$$\lim_{t \to 0}\left(f(t+s) - f(s)\right) = \lim_{t \to 0}f(t) = 0$$

This establishes global continuity. You say you are able to prove it when $f$ is continuous, so you can fill in the rest.

*Remark*: It remains true if we weaken the condition to Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will it work for any other functional equation as well? I mean, can a function which is Riemann integrable on a finite interval be said to be continuous always? If not, what additional conditions does one need for continuity?

Comment: @user467745 No. If $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is Riemann integrable on compact intervals, then it has at least one point of continuity. It is not necessarily continuous everywhere (or even on any given interval). However, for this particular functional equation, continuity at a point implies continuity everywhere.

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much!